# Pandas dataframes: Diff method extremely slow after grouping (groupby)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, grouping, diff

I am dealing with a decent size pd dataframe which is made of approx. 50k rows and 5 columns:

- A, B, C which can be considered as unique identifiers for a product (e.g. the shop it is sold at, the nature of the product, and the brand).
- X which is a variable that can be sorted (e.g. a date on which we recorded the information)
- Y which is the value we are interested in / monitoring (e.g. the number of sales of said product on that date).

What I would like to achieve is to see the diff of Y as a function of X, for each unique combination of A, B, C. This should be very simple using a sorting on X, followed by a groupby on A, B, C, followed by a diff on Y.

I find that the groupby alone is very fast, the diff on the raw data is fast, but the diff coupled with the groupby is painfully slow (1,000x).

1. Groupby operation: 0.005 second
2. Diff operation: 0.005 second
3. groupby+diff : 10 seconds, i.e. 1,000x times the sum of the two individual operations)

Note that my pandas version is 0.24.2

```
import numpy, pandas
from timeit import default_timer as timer

# Initialize dummy df
df = pandas.DataFrame( numpy.random.randint( 0, 100, size=( 50000, 5 ) ), columns=list( 'ABCXY') )

# Groupby
start = timer()
_ = df.sort_values( [ 'X' ], axis=0 ).groupby( list( 'ABC' ) )[ 'Y' ]
print( timer() - start )
    
# Diff
start = timer()
_ = df.sort_values( [ 'X' ], axis=0 )[ 'Y' ].diff()
print( timer() - start )
    
# Groupby + Diff
start = timer()
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
_ = df.sort_values( [ 'X' ], axis=0 ).groupby( list( 'ABC' ) )[ 'Y' ].diff()
print( timer() - start )
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on my system; I get something less than the sum: `0.0796, 0.0687, 0.1075`

Comment: Thanks Nick. Could you please let me know which version of pandas you are using ? I now suspect it may be a 'bug' that has been fixed in later versions of the library.

Comment: I'm using `2.0.1`

Comment: ie the time taken fro the two operations is more or less equivalent to the individual sum of the time taken for each iteration. ie take the mean of the time replicated 50 times

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in a later version of pandas. Sorry for the trouble, the fact that it was working for you Nick gave me a hint and saved me a lot of time, much appreciated !
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45575

Comment: @Matt you might want to post that as an answer (you can accept it yourself) just in case anyone else sees the same issue.